# how to delete one record in first table and insert the in second table in mvc through linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

enter code herehow to delete one record in first table  and insert the in second table in mvc 5 through linqu

and reactive one record in first table  and insert the in second table in mvc 5 through linq

please Suggest me

var queryAllCustomers = from item in db.Clients   // Change for Insert in to DelClient Table
                                    where item.ID_NO == id
                                    select item;

```
        var list1 = new List<Client>();
        var list2 = new List<DelClient>();

        list1 = queryAllCustomers.ToList();
        list1.ForEach(item => list2.Add(new DelClient() { ID_NO = id }));

        foreach (var item1 in queryAllCustomers)
        {
            foreach (var item in list2)
            {
                db.DelClients.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            db.Clients.Remove(item1);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: You should be more accurate when you post a question. Honestly I can't understand what you mean. Can you add code and explain better your problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, find your entry somehow. Add it to the new table. Remove it from the old table. Save Changes.

```
var queryAllCustomers = from item in table
                            where item.id = 1
                            select item;

    ContextName.NewTableName.Add(item);


    ContextName.OldTableName.Remove(item);
    ContextName.SaveChanges();
```

Poor quality question, so not much to go off.